# How to correctly store values in an object's instance?

Tags: python, oop, object

I am learning OOP (normally used to functional programming). This small script here runs, but I am not sure how to permanently save data values in the object (in this case the object's instance is named count, and I am trying to store self.count into the instance).

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class WordCounter:
    def __init__(self, count = 0):
        self.__count = count

    def set_count(self, path):
        try:
            nfile = open(path, "r")
        except:
            print("Could not open file")
        fileList = []
        lowerCaseList = []
        line = nfile.read()
        fileList.append(line.split())
        nfile.close
        lowerCaseList = [word.lower() for word in fileList[0]]
        print(lowerCaseList)
        self.count = len(lowerCaseList)

    def get_word_count(self):
        return self.count

    def __str__(self):
        return "Total word count is: " + str(self.__count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = WordCounter()
    print(count)
    count.set_count("/home/swim/Desktop/word_counter.txt")
    print(count.get_word_count())
    print(count)
```

And here is the output:

Total word count is: 0

['here', 'is', 'a', 'bunch', 'of', 'text.', 'hopefully', 'all', 'of', 'this', 'gets', 'counted', 'correctly.', 'here', 'it', 'goes.']

16

Total word count is: 0

I can see that my get and set methods are working correctly. But how do I get that self.count variable to be stored in the count object?

print(count) evaluates to 0 before and after the get/set.

I was hoping the **str** method would print 16 as well after the line     count.set_count("/path/to/my/text/file")

Any advice? Thank you

Comment: Why have `str(self.__count)` and not `str(self.count)`? You have defined the property twice with different names: `self.count = len(lowerCaseList)` and `self.__count = count
` but you presumably intended them to be the same thing. Also, `nfile.close` does not close the file because you need parentheses to call the close method.

Comment: Why do you use 2 variables to store count?

Comment: Thank you roganjosh. I feel like like a dummy hahaha. Thank you for pointing that out. It is now printing 16 correctly with the __str__ method and correctly saved in the instance.

Comment: don't use double-underscore name-mangling unless you *need name-mangling*. In this case, it doesn't look like you do...

Comment: thank you juanpa.arrivillaga made me chuckle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class WordCounter:
    def __init__(self, count = 0):
        self.__count = count

    def set_count(self, path):
        try:
            nfile = open(path, "r")
        except:
            print("Could not open file")
        fileList = []
        lowerCaseList = []
        line = nfile.read()
        fileList.append(line.split())
        nfile.close()
        lowerCaseList = [word.lower() for word in fileList[0]]
        print(lowerCaseList)
        self.__count = len(lowerCaseList)

    def get_word_count(self):
        return self.__count

    def __str__(self):
        return "Total word count is: " + str(self.__count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = WordCounter()
    print(count)
    count.set_count("/home/swim/Desktop/word_counter.txt")
    print(count.get_word_count())
    print(count)
```

Again thanks roganjosh for pointing out that `self.count` and `self.__count` are supposed to be the same property but were given different names.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the one line in your `__init__` statement to:

`self.count = count`

Answer (score 0):

In your `init` method you used `self.__count = count` that you set `__count` whereas in your getter and setter method you use `self.count` which is different from `self.__count`. And then in your `__str__` method you use `self.__count` which you set in the `__init__` to `0` and never change `self.__count`'s value in your getter or setter.

**So either use `self.__count` in each method or `self.count` in each method**